# Back button on an ad does not bring control back to the android app

Tags: android, android-intent, controls, admob, back-button

When some users click an ad on my app and they are done viewing the ad, and want to come back to the app, if they hit the back button the control goes to the home screen but the app does not crash because they see it running in the background.

I am not overwriting the default behavior of the controls.

What could be causing this or is it the expected behavior ?

Comment: Noticed that this is happening only for adds that redirect to the play store

Comment: What version of Mobile Ads are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest, it comes with 
com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not expected behaviour.

If they are definitely pressing the back button (and not the home button), then it sounds like the intent that displayed the Play Store has been configured to start the Activity in a new Task. Unfortunately, there isn't anything you can do do about this except raise it with the ad network in question.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. Will follow-up with them.